# How to list all tasks in an Azure Batch account using the .NET API?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-batch

In my Azure Batch account, I run many jobs simultaneously. How can I get all tasks across all jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BatchClient.JobOperations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.joboperations?view=azure-dotnet)'s [ListJobs()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.joboperations.listjobs?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Batch_JobOperations_ListJobs_Microsoft_Azure_Batch_DetailLevel_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Microsoft_Azure_Batch_BatchClientBehavior__) and [ListTasks()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.joboperations.listtasks?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Batch_JobOperations_ListTasks_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Batch_DetailLevel_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_Microsoft_Azure_Batch_BatchClientBehavior__):

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Batch;
using Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Auth;
/*...*/

var BatchClient = BatchClient.Open(new BatchSharedKeyCredentials(
  "<your-batch-endpoint>", 
  "<your-batch-account-name>", 
  "<your-shared-key>"));
var jobs = BatchClient.JobOperations.ListJobs();
var tasks = jobs.SelectMany(job => BatchClient.JobOperations.ListTasks(job.Id));
```

Comment: In general, this is not best practice. You will want to design your queries to be efficient across the job and task space you are interested in. Please consult this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-efficient-list-queries